# Electron Package a command line application

Tags: node.js, terminal, electron, command-line-interface, electron-packager

I am currently trying to package my node application index.js and run it from the terminal, like

```
./test testit
```

My setup,

index.js:

```
const commander = require('commander')

commander
    .command('testit')
    .action(function(args) {
        console.log('success')
    })

commander.parse(process.argv)
```

package.json:

```
{
  "name": "test",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Test",
  "main": "index.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "commander": "^3.0.1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "MIT",
  "devDependencies": {
    "electron": "^6.0.9",
    "electron-packager": "^14.0.6"
  }
}
```

I do not need the graphical user interface stuff, I only want it to start from the terminal.

I packaged my application successfully:

```
"electron-packager . --platform=darwin --arch=x64 --app-version=1.0.0 --out=builds
```

But when I execute it from the terminal it is somehow stuck and does not return.. moreover, the electron icon appears in the sidebar, which I don't want to happen... I just want to run it from the CLI.

When i click the electron icon, it shows a dialog with:

```
Uncaught Exception:
TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "path" argument must be of type string. Received type undefined
    at validateString (internal/validators.js:107:11)
    at basename (path.js:1149:5)
    at Command.parse (path/to/dir/test/release-builds/test-darwin-x64/test.app/Contents/Resources/app/node_modules/commander/index.js:446:30)
    at Object.<anonymous> (path/to/dir/test/release-builds/test-darwin-x64/test.app/Contents/Resources/app/index.js:9:11)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:786:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:798:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:645:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:560:12)
    at Object.<anonymous> (path/to/dir/test/release-builds/test-darwin-x64/test.app/Contents/Resources/electron.asar/browser/init.js:181:12)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:786:30)
```

Any ideas on how to only package my app for execution in CLI?

Thanks and greetings!

Comment: More info is needed, including some of the specific code. The two main reasons for a CLI command to appear stuck like that are that it's stuck in a loop, or it's waiting for input of some sort that it's not getting. And there are many, many ways to cause those two problems.

Comment: hey thanks for the anwer, i updated my question and included the whole setup. Can you refer to it?